# How to mass remove function call

Tags: replace

I need to go through hundreds of c++ files and remove a function call and I'm looking for a more automated way of doing this.  Regex is incapable of doing this because, well, c++ is not a regular language.  Here's an example:

`int x = DoSomething(Foo(), Bar(Baz() + Thing()))`

I want to remove the call to Bar, so that I have this:

`int x = DoSomething(Foo(), Baz() + Thing())`

This is just one example, there could be any number of possible variations of the use of the Bar function.  Regex could remove Bar and just leave the ( ), but then I've got a mess of extra parenthesis everywhere which I don't want.  I'd also prefer to disturb the rest of the code as little as possible, so I'd prefer not to do mass removal of all extra parenthesis, unless it's the only option.

I'm hoping there's some kind of sublime text or visual studio code plugin that can do this.

Comment: As far as I am aware, Regex would still be your best bet, albeit it will be a slightly complex Regex. Will have to pattern match the parenthesis as well, look ahead and count to find the proper closing parenthesis to match to also remove.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that can be done.  How do you count with regex?